# Running a .sql file after migrations in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have setup my migrations in django (very small project); but I have a .sql file that has a bunch of data I need in the database.

What is the best way (or is it even possible) to have this .sql file executed after/during running migrations?

The sql file just contains an insert of the data like so:

```
INSERT INTO `mileages_mileages` (`id`, `miles`, `start_location`, `end_location`) VALUES
(NULL,3, 'Location 1', 'Location 2'),
```

I just need to execute that .sql file after running the initial migrations of my models.

Is that possible?

Comment: you can use [RunSQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/migration-operations/#runsql) to run sql inside migrations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading a bit more - running SQL to load data in the migration is the wrong way to go about it. Using [fixtures](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Fixtures) is much better.

I've since added a fixture and will use that file for bringing in the data.

First, to create the fixture I had to add my data to the table (I just ran the SQL file manually to add it to the appropriate table).

Then I ran

```bash
manage.py dumpdata mileage.mileage --indent 2 --format=json --output initial_mileages.json
```

That created my fixture, which I then loaded with

```bash
manage.py loaddata initial_mileages.json
```

and it imported beautifully.

Comment: Worth noting that the Django docs disagree. They say: "If you want to automatically load initial data for an app, don’t use fixtures. Instead, create a migration for your application with RunPython or RunSQL operations." https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/initial-data/ - I don't know that I fully disagree myself though - fixtures seem fine, but SQL is not the *wrong* way.

Comment: Loading fixtures is an extra step which can be forgotten. Plus, when creating test databases, the fixture won't be loaded whereas migrations will be.

Comment: loaddata may only works with INSERT, if any UPDATE needed, please use other ways.

Answer (score 16):

```
migrations.RunSQL()
```

Does not accept a file as input. Only raw SQL. To solve this you need to use either:

```
migrations.RunSQL(
    """
    INSERT INTO 'mileages_mileages' ('id', 'miles', 'start_location', 'end_location') 
    VALUES
       (NULL,3, 'Location 1', 'Location 2');
    """)
```

or

```
def load_data_from_sql(apps, schema_editor):
   file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'file_name.sql')
   sql_statement = open(file_path).read()
   with connection.cursor() as c:
       c.execute(sql_statement)

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('..', '...'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(load_data_from_sql),
    ]
```

Comment: `open(file_path).read()` leaves the file open, better use `from pathlib import Path; Path(file_path).read_text()`.

Comment: If the file is in a package consider using `sql_statement = pkg_resources.resource_string('my.pkg', 'file_name.sql')` instead.

Comment: Also note that the sql file may actually contain multiple statements, it may even create stored procedures; but one shouldn't use `delimiter //` or so, that's only necessary when using `mysql` command and won't work, simply end routines with `END;`.

Comment: Using this approach to add multiple stored routines to MySQL I ran into a `ProgrammingError`: `Commands out of sync`. This was resolved by using `statements = connection.ops.prepare_sql_script(sql_file_content); with connection.schema_editor() as schema_editor: for statement in statements: schema_editor.execute(statement)` instead of using a cursor. Note: I'm piggy backing onto this for multiple statements as this is the first Google hit for "django run sql file after migrations".

Comment: also, not sure if using the cursor from the global connection object puts the statement in the same transaction as the migration's (each migration is isolated in a transaction). `schema_editor` has an `.execute` method which probably is more appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the full script(not perfect, but as is) for converting MySQL statements with DELIMITER to SQL execution.

Information about multiply delimiters in SQL statement https://stackoverflow.com/a/52292690/9521312

### Add script execution in migration file

There are both examples of using script: run sql file or run raw MySQL statement

```
from anywhere import migrate_run_sql

operations = [
              migrations.RunPython(migrate_run_sql.run_sql_file('contract_triggers.sql')),
              migrations.RunPython(migrate_run_sql.run_sql(
                                                           """
                                                           DELIMITER $$
                                                           CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name BEFORE INSERT ON table
                                                           FOR EACH ROW
                                                           BEGIN
                                                             IF NEW.number <> 'anynumber' AND NEW.number <> 'anynumber'
                                                               THEN
                                                                 SET NEW.number = 'anynumber';
                                                             END IF;
                                                           END$$
                                                           """
                                                           ))
             ]
```

### Script file

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.db import connection
import re
from StringIO import StringIO
from django.conf import settings
import os

# this function get raw MySQL statement
def run_sql(sql): 
    def load_data_from_sql(app, schema_editor):
        f = StringIO(sql)
        return _runsql(f)

    return load_data_from_sql

# this function get sql file
def run_sql_file(filename):
    def load_data_from_sql(app, schema_editor):
        filepath = os.path.join(settings.PROJECT_PATH, '../deploy/mysql/', filename)
        with open(filepath, 'rb') as f:
            return _runsql(f)

    return load_data_from_sql

# in this function content splits and checks line by line
def _runsql(f):
    with connection.cursor() as c:
        file_data = f.readlines()
        statement = ''
        delimiter = ';\n'
        for line in file_data:
            if re.findall('DELIMITER', line): # found delimiter
                if re.findall('^\s*DELIMITER\s+(\S+)\s*$', line):
                    delimiter = re.findall('^\s*DELIMITER\s+(\S+)\s*$', line)[0] + '\n'
                    continue
                else:
                    raise SyntaxError('Your usage of DELIMITER is not correct, go and fix it!')
            statement += line # add lines while not met lines with current delimiter
            if line.endswith(delimiter):
                if delimiter != ';\n':
                    statement = statement.replace(';', '; --').replace(delimiter, ';') # found delimiter, add dash symbols (or any symbols you want) for converting MySQL statements with multiply delimiters in SQL statement
                c.execute(statement) # execute current statement
                statement = '' # begin collect next statement
```

Hope it will help!

Comment: Just a question: where is "anywhere"? Your answer is informative but this implicit during the importation makes it tedious to apply for a noob like myself

Comment: @DavidZarebski Sorry for implicit “anywhere”. You should create “migrate_run_sql.py” with content of Script file from my answer in any folder in your django app and import it in the migration file. I use folder “helpers” in my django app for example. Good luck!

Comment: You may want to update your example as you are using the wrong comment character where you have said
```// add lines while not met lines with current delimiter```
Also, for anyone seeing this using Python3 StringIO is not in the io module

E.G 
```from io import StringIO```

Comment: @SteveMapes indeed! Thank you, damn the javascript in another window :)

Answer (score 2):

When using `migrations.RunSQL`, if you get the following error:

> sqlparse is required if you don't split your SQL

You just need to install `sqlparse` to solve the problem:

```bash
pip install sqlparse
```

Comment: Can you explain how to use sqlparse to run the sql insert within a django context?

Comment: @MichaelScottCuthbert I think this package just help django to parse, split and format the SQL scripts only. With me, to perform an insert action, I will choose django model to handle it.
You can run django shell: `python manage.py shell`, then import your django models and then just insert your data like: `YourModel.objects.create(field1=value1, field2=value2)`

Comment: Or pass a list of strings, rather than just a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute a raw SQL

```python
operations = [
    migrations.RunSQL('sql statement here')
]
```

Comment: When I do that I get an error: "sqlparse is required if you don't split your SQL".  Thoughts?

Comment: You need sqlparse

Comment: `pip install sqlparse`

Comment: Great! Thanks - appreciate it!

Comment: Note that the argument to `RunSQL` should be an SQL statement, not a filename. If the SQL statement is too large to reasonably fit into the migration file itself, you may be better off with a `RunPython` operation that loads the file and executes the content.

Comment: To make @knbk's point extra clear, `source file` is a `mysql` command, not a valid SQL statement; either way it doesn't work. See @Jelle's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Inspiration from paveldroo's solution by creating a wrapper around `migrations.RunSQL` to load the sql file:

```py
# core/migrations.py
from pathlib import Path
from typing import AnyStr

from django.db import migrations


def _read_sql_file(path: Path) -> AnyStr:
    with open(path, "r") as sql_file:
        return sql_file.read()


class RunSQLFile(migrations.RunSQL):
    def __init__(
        self,
        sql_file_path: Path,
        reverse_sql=None,
        state_operations=None,
        hints=None,
        elidable=False,
    ):
        sql = _read_sql_file(sql_file_path)
        super().__init__(
            sql=sql,
            reverse_sql=reverse_sql,
            state_operations=state_operations,
            hints=hints,
            elidable=elidable,
        )
```

```py
# app/models.py
class MyModelView(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = "my_model_view"

    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    updated = models.DateTimeField()
```

```sql
-- app/sql/my_model_view.sql
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS my_model_view;

CREATE VIEW my_model_view AS (
  -- SELECT HERE
)
```

```py
# app/migrations/0002_create_my_model_view.py
# Generated by Django 3.2 on 2023-03-06 22:11
from pathlib import Path

from django.db import migrations, models

from core.migrations import RunSQLFile


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ("0001_initial"),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name="MyModelView",
            fields=[
                ("id", models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
                ("name", models.CharField(max_length=1024)),
                ("updated", models.DateTimeField()),
            ],
            options={
                "db_table": "my_model_view",
                "managed": False,
            },
        ),
        RunSQLFile(
            sql_file_path=Path(
                "./app/sql/my_model_view.sql"
            ),
            reverse_sql="DROP VIEW IF EXISTS my_model_view",
        ),
    ]
```